# Programmatically creating a dictionary from a large 2D array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have an 2D array (in Javascript), `RED` with four elements, each of which has another four elements (the parts outside the brackets aren't part of the array, just labels).

```
          Ab  Cd  Ef  Gh
 Red1   [['1','2','3','4'],
 Red2    ['4','3','2','1'],
 Red3    ['5','6','7','8'],
 Red4    ['8','7','6','5']]
```

And I need to convert this into a labeled dictionary (I'm trying to send this through AJAX using jQuery to a Flask Python file.)
So basically I want a dictionary that looks like

```
{red1_ab: 1, red1_cd: 2, red1_ef: 3, red1_gh: 4, red2_ab: 4 ...}
```

How can I do this without creating 16 variables manually? Or is there a way to send a 2D array through jQuery $.getJSON?

For reference, my AJAX call is below (in Javascript).

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn-send-email').click(function() {
        $.getJSON('http://www.example.com/email', {
            exone: example[0],
            extwo: example[1],
            [dictionary objects from array RED go here]
        })
    })
})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's a way to do the structure conversion with a simple for loop or two:

```
var RED = [['1','2','3','4'],
           ['4','3','2','1'],
           ['1','2','3','4'],
           ['4','3','2','1']],
    dictionary = {},
    letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
    i,
    j;
for (i = 0; i < RED.length; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < RED[i].length; j++)
        dictionary["red" + (i+1) + "_" + letters.substr(j*2,2)] = RED[i][j];
```

Or instead of using just a string `letters` you could define the "x axis" labels in an array:

```
    x = ["ab","cd","ef","gh"],
```

...and then:

```
    dictionary["red" + (i+1) + "_" + x[j]] = RED[i][j];
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I thought that Javascript didn't allow users to piece together variable names with other variables.

Comment: In this case they're not variable names, they're object property names. Object properties can be accessed as `someObject.somePropName` or `someObject["somePropName"]` - if you use the `[]` syntax you can include any expression that evaluates as a string that is the property name you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
function objectFromMatrix(matrix, rowNames, columnNames) {
    var obj = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = matrix[i],
            rowName = rowNames[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < currentRow.length; j++) {
            var columnName = columnNames[j];
            obj[rowName + "_" + columnName] = currentRow[j];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

var RED = [['1','2','3','4'],
           ['4','3','2','1'],
           ['5','6','7','8'],
           ['8','7','6','5']];

objectFromMatrix(RED, ["red1", "red2", "red3", "red4"], ["Ab", "Cd", "Ef", "Gh"]);
```